# @ControllerAdvice fails in returning ResponseEntity<T> (T is a POJO)

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, exception

I'm in the process of creating a REST API using Spring 4 MVC.
I wish I could make it possible, when an invalid endpoint is requested, to deliver a default JSON error object.
I've read about the @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler, which I tried to use properly :

```
package com.yopyop.wackend.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;

import com.yopyop.wackend.controller.ErrorResponse;
import com.yopyop.wackend.service.NotFoundException;


@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> exceptionHandler(Exception ex) {

        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());

        if (ex.getClass()==NotFoundException.class) {
            error.setMessage("ExceptionControllerAdvice() Not found");
            error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
            return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        else {
            error.setMessage("ExceptionControllerAdvice() " + ex.getClass() + "(" + ex.getMessage() + ")");
            error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({NoHandlerFoundException.class})
    ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex,
            WebRequest request) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        error.setMessage("ExceptionControllerAdvice() " + ex.getClass() + "(" + ex.getMessage() + ")");

        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

My ErrorResponse class is as follow:

```
package com.yopyop.wackend.controller;

public class ErrorResponse {
    private int errorCode;
    private String message;

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }
    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I modified web.xml so that the NoHandlerFound exception is thrown:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Wackend WebApp</display-name>
  <servlet>
 <servlet-name>wackend</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>

 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>wackend</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Nevetheless, when a request to an unmapped endpoint is received, I get :

```
> 22:47:28.545 [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG
> o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name
> 'wackend' processing GET request for [/wackend/swagger-ui.html]
> 22:47:28.548 [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG
> o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method
> for path /swagger-ui.html 22:47:28.552 [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG
> o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method
> [public void
> com.yopyop.wackend.controller.DefaultController.unmappedRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
> throws org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException]
> 22:47:28.552 [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG
> o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of
> singleton bean 'defaultController' 22:47:28.553
> [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
> Last-Modified value for [/wackend/swagger-ui.html] is: -1 22:47:28.566
> [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG
> o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception
> from handler [public void
> com.yopyop.wackend.controller.DefaultController.unmappedRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
> throws org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException]:
> org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler
> found for GET /wackend/swagger-ui.html, headers={} 22:47:28.567
> [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
> Returning cached instance of singleton bean
> 'exceptionControllerAdvice' 22:47:28.567 [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG
> o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Invoking
> @ExceptionHandler method:
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.yopyop.wackend.controller.ErrorResponse>
> com.yopyop.wackend.controller.ExceptionControllerAdvice.handleNoHandlerFoundException(org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)
> 22:47:28.603 [http-nio-8080-exec-15] ERROR
> o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke
> @ExceptionHandler method:
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.yopyop.wackend.controller.ErrorResponse>
> com.yopyop.wackend.controller.ExceptionControllerAdvice.handleNoHandlerFoundException(org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)
> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
> find acceptable representation    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:134)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:146)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
> ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE] [...]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> [na:1.8.0_101]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> [na:1.8.0_101]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.36]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> [na:1.8.0_101] 22:47:28.603 [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG
> o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception
> from handler [public void
> com.yopyop.wackend.controller.DefaultController.unmappedRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
> throws org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException]:
> org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler
> found for GET /wackend/swagger-ui.html, headers={} 22:47:28.603
> [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
> Returning cached instance of singleton bean
> 'exceptionControllerAdvice' 22:47:28.603 [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG
> o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Invoking
> @ExceptionHandler method:
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.yopyop.wackend.controller.ErrorResponse>
> com.yopyop.wackend.controller.ExceptionControllerAdvice.handleNoHandlerFoundException(org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)
> 22:47:28.604 [http-nio-8080-exec-15] ERROR
> o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke
> @ExceptionHandler method:
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.yopyop.wackend.controller.ErrorResponse>
> com.yopyop.wackend.controller.ExceptionControllerAdvice.handleNoHandlerFoundException(org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)
> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
> find acceptable representation    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:134)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:146)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
> ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE] [...]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> [na:1.8.0_101]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.36]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> [na:1.8.0_101] 22:47:28.604 [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG
> o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from
> handler [public void
> com.yopyop.wackend.controller.DefaultController.unmappedRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
> throws org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException]:
> org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler
> found for GET /wackend/swagger-ui.html, headers={} 22:47:28.604
> [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG
> o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from
> handler [public void
> com.yopyop.wackend.controller.DefaultController.unmappedRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
> throws org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException]:
> org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler
> found for GET /wackend/swagger-ui.html, headers={} 22:47:28.604
> [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null
> ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'wackend':
> assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling 22:47:28.604
> [http-nio-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
> Successfully completed request
```

and then a standard Tomcat 404 page is returned.
Please not that :

1. return new ResponseEntity(error,
   HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

   will return an HTTP 500 with an empty body (better than the Tomcat
       default page)
2. return new ResponseEntity("woot",
           HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); will return an HTTP 500 with woot as a body.

It looks like the JSON mapping can't be done with my ErrorResponse class.

Beside, I use a default controller, but I guess it is useless since I use @ControllerAdvice. I paste it here for information:

```
package com.yopyop.wackend.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;

/**
 * Default controller that exists to return a proper REST response for unmapped requests.
 */
@Controller
public class DefaultController {

    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public void unmappedRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws NoHandlerFoundException {
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        String method = request.getMethod();
        HttpHeaders h = new HttpHeaders();

        throw new NoHandlerFoundException(method, uri, h);
    }
}
```

My REST API also makes use of ResponseEntity<> returns and succeeds in returning proper JSON payloads.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly the answer is but maybe the problem is with JSON configuration. At first your @Controller is not @RestController and you are not specifying explicitly what is produced. I hope you do this in your request, so spring knows what to do. I think the mime type from @Controller is inherited and used to conversion.

You may try to add a breakpoint in your http message converter. In every converter there is a mathod `supports` try to catch your code here. Check which converter is returning true. Spring uses the first one if more than one passes the conditions. Going up through the stacktrace you may also find which converters are available for your request and what kind of converter is required.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/AbstractHttpMessageConverter.html#supports-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log you have attached:

1. you try to request a resource `/wackend/swagger-ui.html`
2. you have `DefaultController` that handles all requests

What you need to do:

1. Read and configure Swagger properly: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-rest-swagger-2-example
2. Add JSON library to support marshling:

- Spring starter: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json
- or https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind